# When do I need to use bind(this)

Tags: javascript, promise, this, bind

I'm having trouble figuring out when do I need to bind the instance to a function.

For example, say I'm using a service function that returns a `Promise<void>` and i dont want to use an anonymous function in my then-chain, i'd like to do something like this:

```
this.someService.somePromiseMethod().then(this.doSomething)`
```

the `doSomething`:

```
public doSomething(){
  this.a = 2
}
```

But this fails since it does not recognize the `a` of this (`undefined`)

While using : `this.someService.somePromiseMethod().then(this.doSomething.bind(this)` works

WHY? The call to the service is done within the instance, why do I still need to bind this instance to the function call?

Thanks in advance for any clarifications!

Comment: Here is the link to the MDN documentation, it's usually well written and with lots of examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Why?  Because your function is not executing in the context of the object to which `this` refers, but a callback invoked by use of a promise.

Comment: @James I see, is there any way of achieving this behavior without adding the `.bind(this)` for every `then` call?

Comment: Perhaps you can define a second function in your class which is a bound copy of your first function (or define the first function as an anonymous function which is then bound to `this`).  I don't use class-based JS much but something like `this.boundFunc = this.func.bind(this);`, and then use `this.boundFunc` as your callback.